# Bootstrap Row MT?

Tags: row

```
<section id="about">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row mt-400 mt-xs-20">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
```

So I have the following code I found.  What does the mt and mt-xs stand for?  Googling brings no related information, is there a doc somewhere that could tell me?

Answer (score 5):

This is a spacing value. The `m` indicates `margin`. The `t` indicates `top`. Therefore it is setting the top margin for your row. The `xs` indicates screen sizes that are considered `extra small`.

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

These are the custom css classes. usually some html templates comes with them. Look for  mt-400 mt-xs-20 in you css file.

code may look like:

```
.mt-400{
margin-top: 400px;
}
```